# Dialog feed not redirecting after proccess

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I am developing simple facebook canvas app. I was following this page in documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

In my app, I would like to encourage users to share it, so I tried to make a feed dialog according to this (first javascript example): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I am able to share a link, but nothing happens after clicking share or cancel. I have defined the redirect_uri parameter a it is the same domain URI as defined in app settings. The weird is, that if I click close button (X), the page in redirect_uri loads inside the iframe dialog lightbox.

Any idea, where should be the problem? Long googling lead to no result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation, the redirect_uri is only for when someone clicks cancel (or closes the dialog without sharing).  I cant tell from their documentation where it goes if they share.  However, the situation of the iframed dialog getting the page nested into it is very odd.  My first instinct is that something is incorrect in the app settings. Ensure you have both the http and https versions of your facebook app specified.

Comment: Thank you for answer. According to documentation, I suppose that redirect_url should be used after every button click. ("The URL to redirect to after the user clicks a button on the Dialog.")
But thats not the biggest problem. As for the app settings: I have no access to server with real https, only with self-signed certificate which throws ugly error. Should this be a problem? Isn't there some workaround when using web server without paid certificate?

Comment: You are required now to have a real https site.  I think that can only be done with a paid certificate.  If not, something is really wrong with the internet and I will never trust being on an https site again...

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is no way to simulate https without having certificate :) But I've meant some workaround on facebook to not require https connection for your canvas app page. Nevertheless, thank you for your answers, now I suspect the missing https to be the problem and trying hosting via some of facebook cloud service partners which seem to be the solution and it also seems to be free for small applications.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same code available in facebook feed dialogue. I changed it to adopt my app requirements and lightbox opens if cancel uses '#' as redirect_uri else I use response function to move document.location to thankyou page, I hope it will help you fixing your problem.

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "<?=$config['appId'];?>", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: '#',
      link: 'https://www.facebook.com/MyPageName/app_<?=$config['appId'];?>',
      picture: 'https://www.abc.com/fbapp/img/welcome.jpg',
      to: friendId,// js variable I am fetching from radio button selection
      name: 'App Blah Blah',
      caption: 'your_caption',
      description: 'your_description'
    };

    function callback(response) {
// I commented out message print in div
//          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];

// check weither feedback is valid
        if(typeof(response)!='undefined'){
            document.location = 'thankyou.php';
        }
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```